# System.DmlException: Insert failed

Tags: apex, custom-object, error

I am having trouble with one of my test classes (PortalControllerTest) which keeps failing validation.

This is the error I receive:

```
    System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CreateOpportunity: execution of BeforeInsert

caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Trigger.CreateOpportunity: line 12, column 1: []
```

**PortalController Apex**:

```
static testMethod void myTest() {
User usr = [Select Id,ContactId From User where ContactId != null AND IsActive = true limit 1];
Service_Order__c sOrder;
System.RunAs(usr)
{
    sOrder = new Service_Order__c();
    sOrder.Name ='SO01';
    sOrder.building__c = 'LHR';
    sOrder.Project_Deadline__c = system.today();
    sOrder.Accept_Terms_Conditions__c = true;
    insert sOrder;

}
```

**CreateOpportunity Trigger**:

```
    trigger CreateOpportunity on Service_Order__c (before insert,after insert){

        Id UserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        User user = [select AccountId, ContactId from User where id=:UserId];

        Account account = [select building__c,LHR__c, ABZ__c, SOU__c, GLA__c, STN__c, EDI__c,OwnerId from account where id=:user.AccountId];

        Set<String> buildingList = new Set<String>();
        if(account.LHR__c) buildingList.add('LHR');
        if(account.EDI__c) buildingList.add('EDI');
        if(account.GLA__c) buildingList.add

('GLA');    
    if(account.SOU__c) buildingList.add('SOU');
    if(account.STN__c) buildingList.add('STN');
    if(account.ABZ__c) buildingList.add('ABZ');    

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.StageName = '04 - Qualification Prebid';


    Service_Order__c ServiceOrder = trigger.new[0];

...
```

From the error message I see it has some kind of relation to a trigger called CreateOpportunity.
I know there are definetly records in the Users table.

Comment: The error is happening on line 12 of the CreateOpportunity trigger. We would need to see that code to be able to help

Comment: Does Service_Order__c depend on Opportunity in any way? Could you provide the code?

Comment: @user8737 Almost, but the other way.. Opportunities are made from Service Orders.

Comment: I have added the relevant section from CreateOpportunity trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several suggestions:

1). If you are trying to use existing data in your unit test class, add `@istest(seealldata=true)`  in the top of the test class (may be you already have this in your code).

```
@istest(seealldata=true)
public class your_testclass{
   // your code
}
```

2). Try to assign your query results into `List` instead of to a single instance.

```
List<User> users = [select AccountId, ContactId from User where id=:UserId];
```

and then work with that list,

```
if(users != null && users.size() > 0){
  List<Account> accounts = [select building__c,LHR__c, ABZ__c, SOU__c, GLA__c, STN__c, EDI__c,OwnerId from account where id=:user[0].AccountId];
}
```

3). If you much sure that there is one record and need to assign into single instance, try

```
User user = [select AccountId, ContactId from User where id=:UserId][0];
Account account = [select building__c,LHR__c, ABZ__c, SOU__c, GLA__c, STN__c, EDI__c,OwnerId from account where id=:user.AccountId][0];
```

(but I don't like this method since it intend to throw exceptions).

Comment: I did have solution 1 already present. The later two suggestions did not work however. Is it possible to see the outputs from the SOQL statements? I want to debug where the issue is, although there are records in the object (4 in total) I am not certain that it is able to view them, possibly down to the conditions in the query.

Comment: Have a usual debug statement.`System.debug(users);` or to check the size `System.debug('Size of the List : ' + users.size());`

Comment: I can see that a row is returned, the size of the list is 1.

Comment: Then try accessing attributes of it to make sure the results .ie; `System.debug('Retrieved Accnt Id : ' + user[0].AccountId);`

Comment: Hmm I'm looking at the execution log, the query for `Account account = [select building__c, LHR__c, ABZ__c, SOU__c, GLA__c, STN__c, EDI__c, OwnerId from account where id=:user.AccountId];` has not returned anything. I believe there is no connecting record with the same foreign key from Users object.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is, because the way the testmethod is written, it will try and fetch details for the currently logged in user (which in my case is the Administrator), I will not have an account record in SF hence why the test fails. What is th best course of action in this case?

Comment: Suggested solutions are to avoid `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject` kind of exceptions. If you need to test by particular user first create those test helper data and then perform your unit test. Check here and manage to create a user as you want. Then execute unit test as it need in the trigger https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm